# jsoup - an element with an attr X in a class Y

Tags: jsoup

```
 <a class="ajaxed nextStation inactive paneLeft" title="Next station" href="somethinf.com"></a>
```

Can i find that element by `jsuop` selector ? I mean an element `a` with attribute `title` set to `Next station` which is in an `inactive` class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
Jsoup.parse(YOUR_HTML).select("a.inactive[title=Next station]");
```

more about [selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)